# Инсталятор не показывает требуемое место на диске

Tags: inno-setup

Мне нужен был код, который реализовывал бы мне нужную функцию. При выборе компонента, второй бы выбирался автоматически. И я нашёл такой код, но вод досада, с ним не показывается значение, которое будет занято после установки.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вот такой:

```
[Components]
Name: "A"; Description: "A"
Name: "B"; Description: "B"

[Code]

const
  ItemA = 0;
  ItemB = 1;

var
  PrevItemAChecked: Boolean;
  TypesComboOnChangePrev: TNotifyEvent;

procedure ComponentsListCheckChanges;
begin
  if PrevItemAChecked <> WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[ItemA] then
  begin
    if WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[ItemA] then
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[ItemB] := True;

    PrevItemAChecked := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[ItemA];
  end;
end;

procedure ComponentsListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ComponentsListCheckChanges;
end;

procedure TypesComboOnChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { First let Inno Setup update the components selection }
  TypesComboOnChangePrev(Sender);
  { And then check for changes }
  ComponentsListCheckChanges;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck := @ComponentsListClickCheck;

  { The Inno Setup itself relies on the WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange, }
  { so we have to preserve its handler. }
  TypesComboOnChangePrev := WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange;
  WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange := @TypesComboOnChange;

  { Remember the initial state }
  { (by now the components are already selected according to }
  { the defaults or the previous installation) }
  PrevItemAChecked := WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[ItemA];
end;
```

Может нужно что-то подправить? Или может есть какая альтернатива?

Answer (score 0):

В конечном итоге получился у меня такой код, работа которого меня устраивает. При выборе компонента А автоматически выбирается В и С. И наоборот при снятии галочки с А убираются 
галочки с B и C.

```
   [Setup]
AppName=myprog
AppVerName=myprog
AppVersion=1.1.1.1
VersionInfoVersion=1.1.1.1
AppCopyright=myprog
AppPublisher=myprog
DefaultDirName={pf}\myprog
DefaultGroupName=myprog
OutputBaseFilename=myprog
Compression=none
ComponentsListTVStyle=true

     [Components]
        Name: "A"; Description: "A"; Flags:  disablenouninstallwarning collapsed;
        Name: "B"; Description: "B" ; Flags:  disablenouninstallwarning collapsed;
        Name: "C"; Description: "C" ; Flags:  disablenouninstallwarning collapsed;
        Name: "C\D"; Description: "CD";   Flags: disablenouninstallwarning exclusive;
        Name: "D\D"; Description: "DD" ;    Flags: disablenouninstallwarning exclusive;

        [Code]
        procedure ComponentsListCheckChanges;
        begin
          if IsComponentSelected('A')=true then
        begin
          WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[1] := True;
          WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[2] := True;
          WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(3);
        end;
         if IsComponentSelected('A')=false then
        begin
          WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[1] := false;
          WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[2] := false;
           WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[3] := false;
          WizardForm.TypesCombo.OnChange(0);
        end;
        end;

        procedure ComponentsListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
        begin
          ComponentsListCheckChanges;
        end;

        procedure InitializeWizard();
        begin
        WizardForm.TypesCombo.ItemIndex:= 2;
        WizardForm.ComponentsList.OnClickCheck := @ComponentsListClickCheck;
        WizardForm.TypesCombo.Hide;
        end;

        [Languages]
        Name: "ru"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\Russian.isl"
        Name: "en"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]